# Pycharm upgrade to 4.0.5 causes issues

Tags: python, ide, pycharm, freeze

I've been using PyCharm 4.0.4 (community edition) for a while without problems and just updated to PyCharm 4.0.5. When trying to modify a project that I had developed in 4.0.4, the IDE suddenly hangs even though I'm simply typing into the editor/adding a comment/etc. I'm not even attempting to run the program. The IDE hangs after about 2-3 minutes of having PyCharm open. Two questions here:

1. Any tips/suggestions/insights on why the issue is occurring or a potential solution to the problem?
2. If no to the above, is there a straightforward way to revert to the previous version?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've also been encountering freezing with 4.0.5 on OSX. Tried removing my old projects created with the previous version of PyCharm and recreating them with 4.0.5 but no effect. I'm trying to find a download for an older version of PyCharm 4 but the [previous release page](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Previous+PyCharm+Releases) only has version 3.

UPDATE: You can download 4.0.4 [here](http://download-cf.jetbrains.com/python/pycharm-community-4.0.4.dmg)

Comment: nice! thanks for the link! Just another follow up on that, did you uninstall 4.0.5 and then install 4.0.4? or just installed 4.0.4 on top of the 4.0.5 installation?

Comment: FYI I've reported this to JetBrains here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-15310

Comment: nice yeah i had searched the pycharm reports and saw that someone had posted a similar issue of the IDE hanging before i brought the issue to stack overflow. Hopefully they make the necessary changes.

Answer (score 2):

I also had problems with the update. I uninstalled Pycharm, then I installed 4.0.5. I haven't had any problems since.

Comment: Same for me. Deleting and reinstalling Pycharm 4.0.5 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have same trouble with the release 4.0.5 uptdated from 4.0.4 on OSX 10.6.8. I resolved the issue by setting the application "PyCharm CE.app" to run in the 32-bit mode (selecting the file and using "Get info" to enable the check box "Open in 32-bit mode").

It works normaly on 32-bit mode.

Comment: Thanks for that info! Since i use pycharm for my development at work, and since 4.0.4 has always worked fine, i probably won't bother attempting to update again. but that's good to know for everyone else!